# How can I fix this error for Flow Layout in java?

Tags: java, flowlayout

I don't know why but I get an error everythime I run this code.

The error is:
***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method setLayout(LayoutManager) in the type JFrame is not applicable for the arguments (FlowLayout)
at gui.FlowLayout.main(FlowLayout.java:14)***

I'm learning Java and I'm a beginner so I don't really know what to do. Please help me.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FlowLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //cerates frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //exit out of application
        frame.setSize(500, 500); //sets x-dimesion, and y-dimension of frame
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        frame.add(new JButton("1"));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a potential conflict between the class you created `gui.FlowLayout` and `java.awt.FlowLayout`, the layout you have to give to your frame.

The error is due to the fact the `JFrame.setLayout()` method expects a `java.awt.FlowLayout` and not a `gui.FlowLayout` which is the only FlowLayout available in your code.

To fix that, I'd do the following

1. Remove the ambiguity by renaming the class you created (to `FlowLayoutExample` for example).
2. Import the `java.awt.FlowLayout` you actually need.

The code should become:

```
package gui;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class FlowLayoutExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //cerates frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //exit out of application
        frame.setSize(500, 500); //sets x-dimesion, and y-dimension of frame
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.add(new JButton("1"));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Note:** there is also another possibility: you can skip the import and directly mention the complete class name (with the package):

```
frame.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
```

I tend to prefer the first solution because:

- The name `FlowLayout` doesn't reflect what your class does while `FlowLayoutExample` is IMHO more explicit.
- Always using complete class names makes your code more verbose and thus less readable.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the library: ***import java.awt.FlowLayout***

Comment: In most cases the import should be done as you have suggested, but the code would still fail in this instance because the issue is caused by having a class with the same name `FlowLayout` as the layout manager `FlowLayout`. The class needs to be renamed or the full package path needs to be used as shown in the answer by another user above `java.awt.FlowLayout()` rather than `FlowLayout()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).